# SQL query that matches multiple rows through several AND clauses in a three table INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry if my title isn't very specific. I just have no idea what this is called, and since I tend to let Rails abstract DB queries for me, more complex ones escape me. I have this query that rails generated:

```
SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks" INNER JOIN "parts" ON "parts"."id" = "stocks"."part_id" 
INNER JOIN "features" ON "features"."part_id" = "parts"."id" INNER JOIN "feature_titles" ON "feature_titles"."id" = "features"."feature_title_id" 
WHERE "parts"."category_id" = 20 AND "stocks"."manufacturer_id" = 4 
AND ((feature_titles.title = 'Title One' AND (features.value = '0.1' OR features.value = '1')) AND (feature_titles.title = 'Title Two' AND (features.value = '200')))
```

The important bits:

`parts(id, number, category_id)`

`features(id, value, feature_title_id, part_id)`

`feature_titles(id, title)`

A quick explanation:

---

Every part can have multiple features. Each feature belongs to a feature_title. Now I need my query to get all parts that has those features associated with their respective feature_titles. Using the example above:

```
parts
---------
id number

1   some part number
2   some other part
```

---

```
features (values aren't strictly integers)
--------------
id  values  feature_title_id  part_id

1     0.1        1               1
2      1         2               1
3     7 MAX      2               2
4     0.1        1               2
```

---

```
feature_titles
-------------------
id  title

1    Title One
2    Title Two
```

---

Doing the query below works.

```
SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks" INNER JOIN "parts" ON "parts"."id" = "stocks"."part_id" 
INNER JOIN "features" ON "features"."part_id" = "parts"."id" INNER JOIN "feature_titles" ON "feature_titles"."id" = "features"."feature_title_id" 
WHERE "parts"."category_id" = 20 AND "stocks"."manufacturer_id" = 4 
AND ((feature_titles.title = 'Title One' AND (features.value = '0.1' OR features.value = '1')))
```

It returns the part with `id` 1. But if I want to further filter by adding another feature_title with and features (see the first problem query), it returns 0 rows. I expect it to return the same single row (in this example). I don't really understand as I thought thats how the AND and OR operators worked. Unless I am missing something.

**EDIT:**

Sorry guys, I'm adding another example to be clearer. Omitting the join since the where seems to be the key:

```
feature_titles.title = 'Title One' AND 
    (features.value = '0.1' OR features.value = '1')
```

Should return parts with id's 1 AND 2. But the query

```
(feature_titles.title = 'Title One' AND (features.value = '0.1')) 
    AND (feature_titles = 'Title Two' AND (features.value = '7 MAX'))
```

Should only return the part with id 2.

Comment: Are those number really strings? What do you have them in quotes?

Comment: Yea @shawnt00. Values can have non integers, hence strings. Edit: or rather, non integer characters.

Comment: You say "adding the AND". Which "AND" are you referring to?

Comment: The first query would have a feature title and feature value with two different values simultaneously. That one would clearly need and OR rather than AND.

Comment: I think that's what you're referring to. Try `OR (feature_titles.title = 'Title Two' AND features.value = '200')`

Comment: @shawnt00 I made an edit. Sorry it wasn't clear. The first query is the problem query. The last one is the one that works.

Comment: And @shawnt00, that wouldn't work. The part needs to have both of those feature_titles. Thats actually what I originally had. It needs to be AND.

Comment: If you want both rows you need an `or`. See my answer for a query that should work. Think of the `where` as operating on a single row at a time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91328/discussion-between-shawnt00-and-andy).

Comment: You're confused about what `and` does. It doesn't say "also allow rows that meet this condition" it says "*all* the values in a single row must meet these conditions". A column can't have two values at the same time so the boolean logic evaluates to false every time. What is `or` for if `and` does what you're expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner query finds the features that match your criteria which are then grouped per part id. The matches features are in different rows of data to verify that a part matches on multiple criteria you have to count the number of rows in that group.

```
SELECT stocks.*
FROM stocks
WHERE part_id IN (
    SELECT part_id
    FROM
        parts ON parts.id = stocks.part_id
        INNER JOIN features ON features.part_id = parts.id
        INNER JOIN feature_titles ON feature_titles.id = features.feature_title_id 
    WHERE
            parts.category_id = 20 AND stocks.manufacturer_id = 4
        AND (
                feature_titles.title = 'Title One' AND features.value = '0.1'
            OR  feature_titles.title = 'Title Two' AND features.value = '7 MAX'
        )
    GROUP BY parts.id
    HAVING COUNT(features.id) = 2
)
```

Comment: You're looking for parts that have both of your features in a single group. In this case it's two. If you had more than the that the count would change accordingly.

Comment: Ahhh. Ok, I'll give it a try!

Comment: It looks like it worked! Thanks so much. One more question for clarification. The having clause. It says `features.id`. Does this mean that if I have this `feature_titles.title = 'Title One' AND (features.value = '0.1' OR features.value = '1')`, does that count as 2? Or is it still considered 1?

Comment: No just one, it's just counting rows (where feature id is not null). Now if you have two rows, one with 0.1 and the other with 1 then that's a different story. For all practical purposes it's the same as `count(*)` here. You might like `count(distinct feature_id)` for clarity in documentation though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an aggregation:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM "stocks" s INNER JOIN
     "parts" p
     ON p."id" = s."part_id" INNER JOIN
     "features" f
     ON f."part_id" = p."id" INNER JOIN
     "feature_titles" ft
     ON ft."id" = f."feature_title_id" 
WHERE p."category_id" = 20 AND s."manufacturer_id" = 4 AND
      ft.title = 'Title One' AND
      (f.value = '0.1' OR f.value = '1')
GROUP BY s.stock_id  -- may need to include all columns here
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT f.value) = 2;  -- makes sure you get both of them
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see the point in all the nested of parens. And I've removed the quotations marks because they're a little distracting to my eye.

```
WHERE
        parts.category_id = 20 AND stocks.manufacturer_id = 4 
    AND (
            feature_titles.title = 'Title One' AND features.value IN ('0.1', '1')
        OR  feature_titles.title = 'Title Two' AND features.value = '200'
    )
```

Looking at the sample data and the queries I can't figure out where the `value` of `'200'` comes from. I'm wondering if you didn't have something like this in mind also.

```
WHERE
        parts.category_id = 20 AND stocks.manufacturer_id = 4 
    AND feature_titles.title = ('Title One', 'Title Two')
    AND features.value IN ('0.1', '1', '200')
```

This second query is looser than the first one but I thought you had said something about search filters.

You refer to "filter further" in your question. There's no way to filter a single result down any more. But don't worry, the confusion over AND/OR seems to pretty common in my experience. It's because of the way we use those terms in spoken English in a non-technical way.

Comment: Ok. I think I am getting it :/. Thats a problem then. I'm not sure how to ensure I only get parts back that meet my criteria. Take my very last query in my edit. I should only get back parts where `Title One` has the value `0.1`, but also `Title Two` with the value `7 MAX`. That part is the point for me. With the `OR`, I can get back parts with values mix and matched. For example, I get back parts with values different than `7 MAX`, when I want it to match those specific values.

Comment: If you've been experimenting and getting incorrect results, I suspect it's because you didn't have parentheses in the right place.

Comment: Using the example tables above, how would I get back a part that has value `0.1` under `Title One` and value `7 MAX` under `Title Two`?

Comment: I didn't look close enough at the data since you added that. You're looking to add multiple criteria to a single part. Gordon, was on the right track in his answer.

Comment: Yessir. Thats the idea. I noticed Gordon's, but it wasn't giving me the result I was expecting when using group by. But I wasn't using it exactly like that. I will try his out now.

Comment: I added a second answer. Gordon's was missing the extra condition.

Answer (score 0):

The center AND should be an OR.  You are basically asking for something that has 'Title One' AND 'Title Two' at the same time.  But it can only be one or the other.
Try this:

```
SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks" INNER JOIN "parts" ON "parts"."id" = "stocks"."part_id" 
INNER JOIN "features" ON "features"."part_id" = "parts"."id" INNER JOIN "feature_titles" ON "feature_titles"."id" = "features"."feature_title_id" 
WHERE "parts"."category_id" = 20 AND "stocks"."manufacturer_id" = 4 
AND ((feature_titles.title = 'Title One' AND (features.value = '0.1' OR features.value = '1')) OR (feature_titles.title = 'Title Two' AND (features.value = '200'))
```